# mem compare arrays to get number of matching bytes

Tags: c, memory, memcmp

```
int a[10];
int b[10];
memcmp(a, b, sizeof(int) * 10);
```

`memcmp()` only tells us which memory block is bigger/smaller since it just returns -1,0,+1.
Is there a way to know number of matching elements in `a[]` and `b[]` just after which the mismatch occurs.

```
Ex: a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    b = {1, 2, 4}
```

Here `memcmp(a, b, sizeof(int)* 3)` would return -1. I want to get 2 as answer
Is there a way we can get number of matching elements with help of `memcmp` or some similar inbuilt function

Comment: A for-loop should be simple enough, I don't know of any built-in functionality for this.

Comment: A question generally needs a language tag. Added C tag. Feel free to *change* this to C++ if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want a low level answer since you must have already rejected the easy way with a loop.

You could XOR the memory block a[0] to a[9] with b[0] to b[9]. The resulting memory will be a block of zeros if, and only if, the original arrays were equal. To get the number of matching elements, count the number of int blocks that have all zero bits.

You could do this blisteringly fast in assembler as the operations are so simple.

Comment: And how exactly do you XOR one memory block with another without using a loop? There is no obvious performance benefit between XOR and `==`. Actually, `==` is probably faster as that check can be integrated in the loop on the assembler level: "branch if equal".

Comment: It's a throwback to my sprite graphics days on Z80 chip. Would depend on your chip architecture as we all know.

Comment: Lundin I wouldn't know for sure; I thought XOR was a very natural operation for a chip to do; just need a couple of NAND gates.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop over the two arrays should suffice:

```
int a[10];
int b[10];
int aLen = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); /* we can do this since arrays are declared on the stack */
int bLen = sizeof(b)/sizeof(int);
int currentContig = 0;
int maxContig = 0;

for (int aIdx = 0, int bIdx = 0; (aIdx < aLen) && (bIdx < bLen); ) {
    if (a[aIdx] == b[bIdx]) {
        currentContig++;
        aIdx++;
        bIdx++;
    }
    else if (a[aIdx] > b[bIdx]) {
        currentContig = 0;
        aIdx++;
    }
    else {
        currentContig = 0;
        bIdx++;
    }
    if (currentContig > maxContig) {
        maxContig = currentContig;
    }
}

fprintf(stdout, "longest contiguous match: %d\n", maxContig);
```

Comment: I do not want to implement it using a for loop.. Want to have very efficient implemenation

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it, I didn't see contiguous matching as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Like below

```
int matched_num=0;
while(a[matched_num]==b[matched_num])
matched_num++;
printf("%d",matched_num);
```

final printed value will be total number of matched element in both arrays.